# Why the alert pop-up is not coming in following scenario?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, alert, jquery-click-event

I'm having a hyperlink and upon clicking on it I want to show tha alert pop-up but it's not working. Can anyone tell me where I'm doing wrong? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B9N94/3/)

Following is my HTML Code:

```
<a href="#" class="que_issue">QUE414</a>
```

Following is my jQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".que_issue").click(function() {
       alert("Jumbo");
    });
});
```

Comment: in the JSFIDDLE example, you have not added jQuery library, please include jQuery library, http://jsfiddle.net/B9N94/3/

Comment: Yes, just include the Jquery. Your code works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[e.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)** to prevent default action of your anchor which will reload the page

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".que_issue").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        alert("Jumbo");
    });
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B9N94/4/)**

---

Edit: Actually, you're missing jQuery in your `jsFiddle`. In the other hand, you've used `#` for your anchor so there's no need to use `e.preventDefault()` here but it's a good habit to use `e.preventDefault()` when you want to prevent a default action from happening such as using AJAX to submit a form.

Comment: Read `OP` question carefully, he added `href="#"` already then how can reload page?

Answer (score 2):

your code is ok. just include the `JQuery` library from the left panel in `jsfiddle`

Answer (score 1):

Because it has a default click function you should try

```
$(".que_issue").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Jumbo");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
$(document).on('click', '.cancel_logo', function(){
    alert("Jumbo");
});
```